# Selenium opens browser in the incorrect position

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenide

I found recently that Selenide/Selenium opens any non-maximized browser at position 10x0 even if I set 0x0 explicitly. The worst part that Selenium returns 0x0 browser window position.

What is the heck? What do I miss?

I tried both pure Selenium and Selenide, same result. The issue detected in Windows only.

- OS Windows 10
- Java 8
- Selenide 5.3.1
- Chrome, IE, FireFox

I`ve tried next:

For Selenide:

```
Configuration.browserPosition = "0x0";
Selenide.open(url);
```

For Selenium:

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0,0));
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code that you tried to achieve this?

Comment: Added to the qestion